# Horizontal scrolling appear in the site when clicking on drop-down list

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm facing a problem with search form in site I'm working on,
The site is in 3 languages ( Turkish, English, Arabic ), I have no problem with Turkish and English ( Left to right) but the problem is with the Arabic version ( Right to left ).

- The Horizontal scroll bar appears like this ->

[The screenshot of the website before clicking on a drop-down list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfeQP.png)

- when clicking on a drop down list in search area the scroll goes to the end of the left ->

[The screenshot of the website after clicking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2L9R.jpg)

I hope you have a solution for this problem

Answer (score 1):

this must be a css problem related to some elements when switching the website style to be from right to left.

if nothing is wrong with the css files it could be related to some javascript plugins that doesn't support right to left websites.

I don't think I can help you more than that!